# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Brevemente, al ejecutar el siguietne codigo:

```
array2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
[(e[i+1]-e[i]) for e,i in zip(array2,range(len(array2)-1))]
```

obtengo este error:

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

¿Cuál es la fuente del error?

Comment: Estás intentando indizar sobre un entero, `e` es cada valor de `array2`, enteros. ¿Que quieres conseguir como resultado?

Comment: Ya encontré el error, tienes razón, debo indexar directamente sobre array2. Muchas gracias.

Comment: JVL mirate mi respuesta, aunque el error se soluciona indizando sobre el array como comentas, lo que haces es muy ineficiente, dado que estás usando NumPy. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que se está intentando indizar sobre los items del array (enteros) y como el error muestra no se puede indizar sobre un escalar. zip en cada iteración toma un item de cada iterable (array2 y range) y los retorna, por lo que en cada iteración `e` es un elemento de `array2`, un entero. En todo caso deberemos hacer:

> ```
> >>> array2 = np.array([3, 11, 7, 6, 1, 13, 9])
>
> >>> [(array2[i+1] - e) for e, i in zip(array2, range(len(array2)-1))])
>
> [8, -4, -1, -5, 12, -4]
> ```

Dicho esto puedes  usar `enumerate` y no `zip` + `range` lo cual simplifica el código y es algo más eficiente:

> ```
> >>> [(array2[i+1]- e) for i, e in enumerate(array2[:-1])]
> ```
>
> **Nota:** `array2[:-1]` genera una vista, no se copia el array en ningún momento.

No obstante , te aconsejo que cuando uses NumPy intentes ceñirte a dicha librería y aprovechar la posibilidad de vectorizar las operaciones que ofrece en vez de recurrir a métodos de Python estándar con ciclos. La respuesta general para estos casos es usar `numpy.roll` y vectorizar la recta:

> ```
> >>> (np.roll(array2, -1) - array2)[:-1]    
> [ 8 -4 -1 -5 12 -4]
> ```

No obstante dado que simplemente desplazas en una posición es mucho más simple y eficiente indizar generando dos vistas y realizar la resta vectorizada:

> ```
> >>> array2[1:] - array2[:-1]
> [ 8 -4 -1 -5 12 -4]
> ```

Muy simple, menos código y muchísimo más eficiente. Un pequeño test de eficiencia:

> ```
> import numpy as np
> array2 = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10000)
>  
> %%timeit
> [(array2[i+1]- e) for e, i in zip(array2, range(len(array2)-1))]
> 3.02 ms ± 48.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> %%timeit
> (np.roll(array2, -1) - array2)[:-1]
> 40.1 µs ± 476 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>
> %%timeit
> array2[1:] - array2[:-1]
> 5.86 µs ± 45.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
> ```

De 3 ms a menos de 6 µs... ;)